# Prevent bootstrap modal from closing on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal.  When the user clicks the "Update" button it makes an ajax call to update the DB.  However if the update fails for some reason I want to display the error message and leave the modal open.

Everything appears to be working in the order I expect, however the `e.preventDefault()` doesn't appear to stop the modal from closing.

Why is the `preventDefault()` not stopping the button from submitting?

My button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdate" style="margin-right:10px">Update</button>
```

Javascript button click code.

```
$("#btnUpdate").on("click", function (e) {
    // reset the message...
    $("#errorMessage").html("");

    // get the value...
    var myParam = $("#someSelection").attr("someData");
    var myParamData = JSON.parse(myParam );

    updateData(myParamData.Name)
    .done(function (result) {
        if (!result.d == "") {
            $("#errorMessage").html(result.d);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {                     
          loadData();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the type of the button to `button` will prevent the submit :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdate" style="margin-right:10px">Update</button>
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Update :**

To profit from HTML5 validation when you're using submition by ajax you could use **[checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity)** method.

> The HTMLSelectElement.checkValidity() method checks whether the element has any constraints and whether it satisfies them. If the element fails its constraints, the browser fires a cancelable invalid event at the element, and then returns false.

So your code will be :

```
$("#btnUpdate").on("click", function (e) {
  // reset the message...
  $("#errorMessage").html("");

  if($("form")[0].checkValidity()) {
    // get the value...
    var myParam = $("#someSelection").attr("someData");
    var myParamData = JSON.parse(myParam );

    updateData(myParamData.Name)
      .done(function (result) {
      if (!result.d == "") {
        $("#errorMessage").html(result.d);
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {                     
        loadData();
      }
    });
  }else{
    console.log("invalid form");
  }
});
```

Comment: This does help, but causes issues with my client side validation.  I changed the button  from submit to button and added some to code to close the modal on a success and that is fine... However in the modal I have 2 input fields which I added the "required" attribute.  That now stops working since it is no longer a submit button.  I guess I can handle the error checking entirely server side, but ultimately was hoping to do validation on both the client and server.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, however doesn't work for me.  I think I have a flaw in my mater page.  I have <form runat=server> and none of my bootstrap modals are rendering the <form> tag when I examine the html.

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` is called from a callback function of `updateData` method, it is quite possible that event is completed before callback is called.

Try placing `e.preventDefault()` before calling `updateData` method.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The 'Native' modal that comes with Bootstrap doesn't seem to be friendly to javascript programmer, see below for an alternative plugin:

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
  title: 'Ajax check',
  message: 'Click buttons below',
  buttons: [{
    label: 'Submit',
    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
    action: function(dialogRef) {
      // Assuming here starts a new ajax request
      $.when().done(function() {
        var ok = false;
        if(!ok) {
          dialogRef.setMessage('<div class="alert alert-warning">Dude, something went wrong!</div>');
        } else {
          alert('Great!');
        }
      });
    }
  }, {
        label: 'Cancel',
        action: function(dialogRef) {
          dialogRef.close();
        }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
```

Read more about the plugin here http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/